# Como fazer essa expressão regular em python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Preciso fazer uma expressão regular para extrair os links dessa string :

```
links =('href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=01GV&id_grupo=70>ADMINISTRAÇÃO - GOVERNADOR VALADARES - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO A</a></li><li><a href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=01GV&id_grupo=71>ADMINISTRAÇÃO - GOVERNADOR VALADARES - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO B</a></li>
```

A string é muito maior. Coloquei só uma parte porque o resto se repete. Eis o que eu já tentei :

```
campus1 = re.findall("href", links)
campus2 = re.findall("http", links)
campus3 = re.findall("href=http", links)
campus4 = re.findall("hre", links)
campus5 = re.findall("a", links)
campus6 = re.findall("<a> <\a>", links)
```

Quando eu dou um print ou saem as letras separadas ou saem ao link e esses nomes( que depois também vou ter que pensar em uma expressão pra pegar somente esses nomes de faculdades)
Alguém alguma ideia ?
O que sai é isso quando eu executo campus1 = re.findall("href", links), por exemplo:
'href', 'href', 'href', 'href', 'href', 'href', 'href', 'href', 'href', 'href', 'href', 'href'... Ou seja, retorna todos os "href's" da string.
Eu gostaria de extrair somente os links, por exemplo:

http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=01GV&id_grupo=70

Todos os links assim que estão nessa string.

Comment: Essa sua string está incorreta... Pois a 1ª `li e o a` estão sem as respectivas aberturas... E o que exatamente deseja extrair, se possível edite com as correções e um exemplo de qual a saída deseja...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça assim :

```
import re
s = "<li><a>href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=01GV&id_grupo=70>ADMINISTRAÇÃO - GOVERNADOR VALADARES - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO A</a></li><li><a href=http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=01GV&id_grupo=71>ADMINISTRAÇÃO - GOVERNADOR VALADARES - DIURNO - SISU - GRUPO B</a></li>"
print(re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', s))
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Mnpkbf)

Explicação da [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/2VtRip/1)(em inglês)

Comment: Eu sei que não se deve usar comentário para agradecer mas vou fazer isso assim mesmo, até porque, se a gente não informar que o negócio deu certo, tanto quem respondeu quanto quem vier nesta pergunta atrás de respostas saberá que funcionou !!!!!!!!!  Então fica aqui meu muito obrigado, deu certinho. vlw !

Comment: a melhor foram de fazer isso é validar a resposta clicando no icon verde abaixo as setas de avaliação da resposta escolhida.. Vlw